# Python:: Read file includes strings, floats and integers

Tags: python, with-statement

I am trying to read a file includes string, floats and integers in a form of matrix,
I tried the following code:[image: data file]

```
import numpy as np

with open('data.dat', 'r') as f:
     input_data = f.readlines()
for p in input_data:
    pizza_details = p.split(",")

print(pizza_details[1][0])
# pizza =[[1 3389.0  36]
          [2 3148.0   28]
          [3 3012.0   40]
          [4 3321.0   61]
          [5 1761.0   41]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `print(pizza_details[1][0])` is the part that still works and you want to get it into a numpy format?

It seems you didnt initialize `pizza_details`, so it keeps getting overwritten within the loop and only the last row is in it after the loop. Initialize it as empty array before the loop and then within the loop add the split row to it.

```
import numpy as np
with open('data.dat', 'r') as f:
     input_data = f.readlines()
pizza_details = []
for p in input_data:
    pizza_details.append(p.split(","))
```

now this is a list of lists

```
print(pizza_details)
> [['1', '3389.0', '36'], ['2', '3148.0', '28'], ['3', '3012.0', '40'], ['4', '3321.0', '61'], ['5', '1761.0', '41']]
```

now convert to numpy 2D array (all values are still string)

```
pizza_details = np.array(pizza_details)
print(pizza_details)
> [['1' '3389.0' '36']
  ['2' '3148.0' '28']
  ['3' '3012.0' '40']
  ['4' '3321.0' '61']
  ['5' '1761.0' '41']]
```

now set type to float so you can use the numerical values

```
pizza_details = pizza_details.astype(float)
print(pizza_details)
> [[1.000e+00 3.389e+03 3.600e+01]
  [2.000e+00 3.148e+03 2.800e+01]
  [3.000e+00 3.012e+03 4.000e+01]
  [4.000e+00 3.321e+03 6.100e+01]
  [5.000e+00 1.761e+03 4.100e+01]]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, 

but when I try to get the first column only [1,2,3,4,5] via pizza_details[0,:], I got any error "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1"

Comment: Did you do the conversion to np.array? (`pizza_details = np.array(pizza_details)`). Afterwards you should be able to access the first row (`pizza_details[0,:]`) or first column (`pizza_details[:,0]`).

Comment: Also IndexError indicates that the 2D array might not look like expected, perhaps try to print it out and see if it really has the right matrix form.